# Como mostrar exceções levantadas no Datasnap REST Server, no client?

Tags: delphi

Muito boa tarde, pessoal.
Então, estou com o seguinte problema. Criei uma Aplicação multicamadas, utilizando o Datasnap REST Server.
Implementei o server com todos os servermethods e também o cliente, até aí tudo bem... 
Estou utilizando o Reflection do Firedac para trazer os dados e o FDMemTable para Listá-los. Só que quando ha algum erro de banco, somente o Server mostrar a mensagem de 
erro e no client não mostra, dificultando assim a manutenção e muito ruim pra identificar erros, porque se eu tiver 2 máquinas, uma com o server e outra com o client, somente é mostrado o erro no Server, eu tenho que ir la pra saber o que está acontecendo.
Alguém ja conseguiu fazer mostrar o erro no client? Sem usar OnReconcileError, pois o crud é feito por métodos passando o objeto por parâmetro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poderia fazer da seguinte forma, passar como parâmetro na função do server o tipo `out`, pois ele te retorna o valor depois que o cliente faz a requisição. Por exemplo:

```
Servidor:
function grava(out psVariavel: String): Boolean;
```

no cliente quando você chamar essa função você passa como parâmetro, uma variável ou um FDMemTable, assim ele vai te retornar o que acontecer no servidor.

Espero te sido claro. Abraços!